# Create a determined quantity of rows based on a dataset in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset:

```
dataloc <- data.frame(id = c("FAS","FAS","FAS","FES","FES"),
                      gen = c(9,0,0,8,0),
                      lipd = c(0,2,3,0,5),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

So I have two groups: `FAS` and `FES`. For each group I want to create 3 rows which repeats the non zero value of `gen`, a row for each non-zero value of `lipd` and a final row that substract `lipd` sum from `gen`. Each row has a defined name. This is the expected output:

```
Name    Value
First   9
Second  9
Third   9
Added   2
Added   3
Result  4
First   8
Second  8
Third   8
Added   5
Result  3
```

I can create the result row with this code:

```
dataloc %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(gen) - sum(lipd)) %>% 
  mutate(name = "Result") %>% 
  select("name","value")
```

But I kind of stuck in creating n rows based on non-zero values and name them. Any help in R base or tidyverse will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R solution. Maybe there are simpler solutions but this one works.

```
sp <- split(dataloc, dataloc$id)


res <- lapply(sp, function(DF){
  i <- which(DF[['gen']] != 0)
  j <- which(DF[['lipd']] != 0)
  tmp <- rbind(DF[rep(i, 3), ], DF[j, ])
  Value <- rowSums(tmp[-1])
  Value <- c(Value, Value[1] - sum(DF[j, 'lipd']))
  Name <- c("First", "Second", "Third", rep("Added", length(j)), "Result")
  id <- rep(DF[['id']][1], length(Name))
  data.frame(id, Name, Value)
})

res <- do.call(rbind, res)
row.names(res) <- NULL
res
#    id   Name Value
#1  FAS  First     9
#2  FAS Second     9
#3  FAS  Third     9
#4  FAS  Added     2
#5  FAS  Added     3
#6  FAS Result     4
#7  FES  First     8
#8  FES Second     8
#9  FES  Third     8
#10 FES  Added     5
#11 FES Result     3
```

Final clean-up.

```
rm(sp)
```

Comment: Hello @Rui Barradas, that's a great answer because it contains multiple concepts!. Please, can I ask you a final question? I forgot the id column, so what should I add to the code to preserve the id column?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and kind answer @Rui Barradas, now that made me investigate more on do.call, which improves my learning. Have a great weekend!